# bigcommerce oAuth order API not work proper

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, bigcommerce

I am using bigcommerce api to get orders.
Bigcommerce introduce new api using  oAuth 2.0. I try to configure it but faild.
Is there any solution to figure it out.

Comment: can you show what you have done so far? https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/guides/curl_quickstart shows you how to get orders using the new API.

Comment: Are you using the Bigcommerce PHP library on Github?

Comment: Do you have your oAuth credentials for accessing your store already?  If so the process to access orders is basically the same as for Basic Auth, your API path and headers are the only difference.  
What method are you using to make your request?  What response have you received?